# Will cardinality concept - (Size of the set) comes under Operations of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying out my few problems in set builder form using binary relations. In workout problems it is mentioned that we must use only set operations to solve the exercise, I would like to know if cardinality is part of set operations or not?

Comment: Not in the sense of $\cup,\ \cap,\ \setminus,\ \Delta$ by any means.

Comment: Cardinality is not the length of a set, it's the size of a set. Length can be assigned to sets of real numbers, but not in general to arbitrary sets.

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes its size will edit it! Thank you

Comment: @SaucyO'Path got it thank you!

Comment: What is the length Q?  Of R - Q?   Of Z?  Or of those sets intersected with [0,111]? @AsafKaragila